# Placing a div's parent sibling in front of the div and making the div slide out on mouseover

Tags: css, z-index

So the situation is when we start:

[jsfiddle of situation where we start](http://jsfiddle.net/hL5gW/)

it should be a menu, the menu has a link called some title. When you hover over "some title" the div behind it should slide out and come into view.

So phase one, with nothing happened, just how it looks without hover is this:

[image]

then we hover it and it should look like this

[image]

Code I tried my luck with:

```
<div style="height: 100px">some text blablablablablablabla <br/> some text blablablablablablabla <br/> some text <br/> some text <br/> some text <br/> some text <br/> some text <br/> </div>


 <nav class="navigation">
   <div class="navfake"></div>
        <div class="singleelement">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="title">
                    Some Title1
                </div>
                <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="singleelement">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="title">
                    Some Title2
                </div>
                <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.navfake{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: green;
      z-index: 10;
  }

.singleelement {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}


.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
   transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  }

 .singleelement .container:hover {
      transform: translate3d(0,-60px,0);
}

.titlepicture {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background: red;
      z-index: -5;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

.title{
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need just simple css drop down menu, is that right? If so check out and follow each steps, it might help.

http://candpgeneration.com/toys/CSS3-dropdown-tut.php

Comment: actually not, but the css there opened up some tricks, the height:0 overflow: hidden trick ;D so +1

Answer (score 1):

I think this should get you started: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL5gW/2/)

```
.titlepicture {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webenter link description herekit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
.singleelement:hover .titlepicture {
    margin-top: -110px;
    height: 90px;
}
.singleelement:hover .title {
    height: 140px;
    background: green;
    margin-top: -120px;
}
.title {
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8hVWz/3/)

the trick is basically simple. Apply z-index only together with position: absolute, relative or fixed.
So i did this:

```
    nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.navfake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 10;
    position:relative;
}
.singleelement {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
     -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
        -o-transition: all .8s ease;
        transition: all .8s ease;
    height: 200px;
}
.titlepicture {
    position:absolute;         /*THIS ADDED*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:10;            /*THIS ADDED*/
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.container:hover {
    top: -80px;
}

.container:hover .titlepicture{
    height:100px;
    z-index:10;

}

.title{                         /*THIS ADDED*/
    z-index:555; 
    position:relative;
    height: 20px;

}

.footer{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="">some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>xxx
</div>

<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="navfake"></div>
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Some Title1</div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Some Title2</div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="footer">some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>xxx
</div>
```